# Is there a tool for previewing both LaTeX and MetaPost files?

Tags: latex

I'm trying to find a tool for Windows that I can use to preview .tex and .mp files as they are saved. Does such a tool exist? I have TeXworks installed which has a handy build button (this displays the result in another window), but I'd rather use Emacs. Also, TeXworks does not compile .mp files.

Perhaps there's a more elegant way to preview files, other than the approach I'm thinking of.

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Are you sure Shay? LaTeX questions don't usually get asked on superuser. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex with http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/latex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use `pdflatex` and [Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/), since this viewer auto-reloads the file.